# Previous weekday in Python

Tags: python, date, weekday

In Python, given a date, how do I find the preceding weekday? (Weekdays are Mon to Fri. I don't care about holidays)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simply subtract a day from the given date, then check if the date is a weekday. If not, subtract another, until you do have a weekday:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def prev_weekday(adate):
    adate -= timedelta(days=1)
    while adate.weekday() > 4: # Mon-Fri are 0-4
        adate -= timedelta(days=1)
    return adate
```

Demo:

```
>>> prev_weekday(date.today())
datetime.date(2012, 8, 20)
>>> prev_weekday(date(2012, 8, 20))
datetime.date(2012, 8, 17)
```

Alternatively, use an offset table; no need to make this a mapping, a tuple will do just fine:

```
_offsets = (3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
def prev_weekday(adate):
    return adate - timedelta(days=_offsets[adate.weekday()])
```

Comment: or  just `return adate - timedelta(days=[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2][adate.weekday()])`

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen: yes, that's what the code in the last example does.

Answer (score 1):

See the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module, in particular the `date()` and `weekday()` function. For example:

```
import datetime

temp = datetime.date(2012,8,21) # Today's date: 2012/08/21
print temp.weekday()
```

This will output `1`. `0` stands for Monday, `1` for Tuesday, etc., until `6` for Sunday. Finding the preceding weekday is easy from here.

Answer (score 1):

in datetime module you can do something like this: `a = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)`
and then `a.weekday()`. Where monday is 0 and sunday is 6.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but anyway, a simpler way to do that, which doesn't require loops

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.strptime('2023-10-14',  '%Y-%m-%d')
today = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
weekday = 6
days = today.isoweekday() - weekday
if days<=0:
    days += 7
previous_date = today - timedelta(days=days)
print(previous_date) # 2023-10-07 00:00:00 (Saturday = day 6 of the week )
```

Comment: This is not correct. 2023-10-15 (a Sunday), this returns 2023-10-14 (Saturday). For 2023-10-14 (Saturday), this returns 2023-10-09 (Monday).

Comment: For this code, if you want to find the previous weekday with respect to the same with the same weekday it will return the same day, to avoid this and get the day of the previous week in the condition to get 7 days previous if the days is 0 `days<=0`. You can also put the hours minutes and second t 0 to avoid problems when subtracting the days. I edited the answer.

Comment: Still not correct: whatever date I enter, the code now returns the Saturday of the week before. The author asked to get the previous Weekday (Mon-Fri). Example with dates in Oct 2023: Mon9->Fri6, Tue10->Mon9, Wed11->Tue10, Thu12->Wed11, Fri13->Thu12, Sat14->Fri13, Sun15->Fri13. Above answer by Marijn Pieters contains two working approaches, so no need to rack your brain ;-)